# App Freezes for few seconds While fetching and storing contact from phone to SQLite table

Tags: android, listview, contacts

I'm trying to fetch phone contact and storing it into SQLite table all working fine but app freezes for few seconds.please help me to overcome with this problem.thanks in advance.

I tried with Async task but it showing the error message that only UI thread touch its views

```
public class ContactsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private DataBaseHelper db;
    private ListView listView;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private List<String> namelist=null;
    //private Button btnLoad;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_contacts);
        listView = findViewById(R.id.listView);
        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        //btnLoad = findViewById(R.id.btnLoad);
        db=new DataBaseHelper(ContactsActivity.this);
        namelist = db.getData();

        if(namelist.size()>0)
        {
            ArrayAdapter listadapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplication(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,namelist);
            listView.setAdapter(listadapter);
            listadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        else{
//            AsyncTask.execute(this::getcontacts);
            getcontacts();
        }

    }
    public void getcontacts()
    {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            db=new DataBaseHelper(ContactsActivity.this);
            ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
            Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                    null, null, null, null);
            assert cur != null;
            if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
                while (cur.moveToNext()) {
                    String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                    if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(
                            cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
                        Cursor pCur = cr.query(
                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                                null,
                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?",
                                new String[]{id}, null);
                        assert pCur != null;
                        while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                            String phoneNo = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                            String Name = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
                            db.insert(Name,phoneNo);

                        }
                        pCur.close();
                    }
                }
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                        namelist = db.getData();
                        ArrayAdapter listadapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplication(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,namelist);
                        listView.setAdapter(listadapter);
                        listadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                cur.close();
            }
    }

}
```

I just want that app run smoothly without blocking the Main thread.

Comment: just dont run DB operations in main thread. Run them async

Comment: Use the `onPreExecute` and `onPostExecute` of the async and move the `progressBar` updates and `listAdapter` updates to those portions of the async - they run on uithread while the db stuff should be in the `doInBackground`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `AsyncTask`

```
private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    // Do your background task here [get contacts]
    return "";
}      

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {               
    //Task to be done after your background task is done like updating UI etc
 }
}
```

Please check the developer link for details: [Async Task](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask)

Answer (score 0):

You should call getContacts() method in a worker thread and send the result to the main thread.

```
   new AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<String>>() {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<String> strings) {
            // Ui Thread operations
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            ArrayAdapter listadapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplication(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,strings);
            listView.setAdapter(listadapter);
            listadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        protected List<String> doInBackground(Void... voids) {

            db=new DataBaseHelper(ContactsActivity.this);
            ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
            Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                    null, null, null, null);
            assert cur != null;
            if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
                while (cur.moveToNext()) {
                    String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                    if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(
                            cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
                        Cursor pCur = cr.query(
                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                                null,
                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?",
                                new String[]{id}, null);
                        assert pCur != null;
                        while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                            String phoneNo = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                            String Name = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
                            db.insert(Name,phoneNo);

                        }
                        pCur.close();
                    }
                }
                namelist = db.getData();
                cur.close();
            }

            return namelist;
        }
    };
```